# When can one write $f(x,y)$ as $|g(x)-g(y)|_2^2$ for some $g(\cdot)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, functional-equations

Suppose I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Fix a natural number $k$. Under what conditions can I write 
$$
f(x,y) = [g(x) - g(y)]^{T}[g(x) - g(y)]
$$
for some appropriate function $g:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$?

Necessary conditions are obviously that $f(x,y) \geq 0$, $f(x,x) = 0$ and that $f(x,y) = f(y,x)$, but are these sufficient?

Comment: Maybe $f(x,y)$ is a constant??? I kind of faced a similar problem.

Comment: What does $||g(x)-g(y)||_2^2$ mean here? Or did you just mean $|g(x)-g(y)|^2$?

Comment: $\|g(x)-g(y)\|_2^2 = (g(x)-g(y))^T(g(x)-g(y))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is one more condition: $f(x,y)=f(x,0)+f(y,0)-2\sqrt {f(x,0)f(y,0)}$. This condition and the three conditions you have are necessary and sufficient.

Comment: This seems right to me, at least in the scalar valued case --  Any idea where I could find a reference or proof?

Comment: I've clarified my question; see above. After experimenting a bit numerically, I think this condition only works for the case $k=1$.

Comment: The conditions I have given are sufficient for any k. [ Take $g(x)=(\sqrt {f(x,0)},0,0.,,,0)$. I feel that there is no simple necessary and sufficient condition for k>1.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you wrote:

$f(x,y)= |g(x)-g(y)|^2$, we can find a $k\in \mathbb{R^n}$, such that

$|g(x)-g(y)|^2 \leq |kx-ky|^4 \implies |g(x)-g(y)| \leq |kx-ky|^2 \implies \frac{ |g(x)-g(y)|}{|kx-ky|} \leq |kx-ky| \implies -|kx-ky| \leq \frac{ g(x)-g(y)}{kx-ky} \leq |kx-ky| \implies -k|kx-ky| \leq \frac{ g(x)-g(y)}{x-y} \leq k|kx-ky|$
As $x \rightarrow y$, $|kx-ky| \rightarrow 0$.
Hence, by Sandwich Theorem, we can see that 
$ lim_(x \rightarrow y) [\frac{ g(x)-g(y)}{x-y}]=0 \implies g(x)=g(y)=constant$
Hence $f(x,y)=0$

Comment: I'm not able to follow this argument.